# Missing libraries/modules from Perfect framework on Linux

Tags: linux, swift, module, server, perfect

I am a newbie learning how to code in Swift on Linux.
Right now I am trying to use Perfect framework so I can create th REST service (or something like that) I am following instructions in this

```
https://videos.raywenderlich.com/courses/77-server-side-swift-with-perfect/lessons/1
```

video (I have found a link on perfect.org site) and I did everything just like in the video, but the problem occurs when I have to edit the main.swift file and use `include` to use the PerfectLib, PerfectHTTP and PerfectHTTPServer libraries/modules(?). When I run it the error shows on the terminal saying:

```
main.swift:1:8: error: no such module 'PerfectHTTP'
import PerfectHTTP
```

Same with other modules. Do I have to place downloaded files from Perfect to some special directory within swift directory? Or maybe the files in download link are not complete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before doing any Server Side Swift, please temporarily forget Xcode and try a new tool chain called Swift Package Manager. Open a terminal in a blank folder and type `swift package init` then it will setup a blank project which contains a `Package.swift`, a folder named `Sources` and a `Tests` directory as well.

Now you have to edit the `Package.swift` before import anything into your source code. For example, the starter template Perfect server has such a `Package.swift`:

```
import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "PerfectTemplate",
    targets: [],
    dependencies: [
        .Package(url: "https://github.com/PerfectlySoft/Perfect-HTTPServer.git", majorVersion: 2)
    ]
 )
```

Then you can import any Perfect libraries included in the Perfect-HTTPServer.git

Here is the importing part as defined in the `main.swift` of PerfectTemplate:

```
import PerfectLib
import PerfectHTTP
import PerfectHTTPServer
```

So I will suggest that the best practice is to try Perfect Assistant: https://assistant.perfect.org/perfectassistant/Perfect%20Assistant.dmg which can save most tricky operations such as dependency management, building on linux and production server deployment.

For more information about Perfect other than tutorial video, see this link: http://www.perfect.org/docs/

Comment: **Do not use signature, taglines, or greetings.** https://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior